# How to perform Hilbert transform by using fir hilbert transformer coefficient

Tags: matlab

I just read a paper which gives a 7-element FIR Hilbert transformer:

```
[-0.1270413, 0 -0.6012845, 0, 0.6012845, 0, 0.1270413]
```

This can be found in "On the Behavior of Minimax FIR Digital Hilbert Transformers" by Rabiner and Schafer, 1974. I want to know how to use the transformer coefficients to perform Hilbert transform, equivalently to using matlab function `hilbert()` that is based on `fft`.

For example, I have a simple harmonic signal:

```
y = ac*cos(2*pi*fx*x)
```

The `hilbert()` function can be used to obtain the amplitude ac by:

```
ac =  abs(hilbert(y))
```

My question is how to obtain the amplitude by using the 7-element hilbert transformer?

I tried to directly convolve `y` with those coefficients, then found that the signal phase is shifted but its magnitude is much attenuated.

[image]

Comment: You may need to code your own "Hilbert transform". Have you looked at `fir1`?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to use these given hilbert transformer coefficients?

Comment: Is there anything in the documentation of the fucntion that you dont understand?

Comment: @AnderBiguri: fir1.m does not involve hilbert transform

Comment: Why would you want to compute the Hilbert transform using a FIR filter? Why not through the Frequency domain, where it’s easy and accurate?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the amplitude is mismatched is because of the frequency respsone for the given Hilbert solution, as indicated by the plot below showing the amplitude as well as the phase when compared to a matched compensating delay of 3 samples. The amplitude difference from the plot above should match that exactly for the given frequency in the amplitude response below

[image: OP 7 element Hilbert]

The difference in the OP's sine wave amplitude is about -4.5 dB, indicating the frequency is about 0.4 rad/sample.

For comparison, below is an alternate solution where I extended the bandwidth at the expense of amplitude error:

```
coeff = [ 0.16761102, -0, 0.62093698, -0, -0.62093698, -0,-0.16761102])
```

[image: revised 7 tap Hilbert]

The other solution would be to increase the number of coefficients. Below shows the achieved performance with 15 taps.

[image: revised 15 tap Hilbert]

And with 51 taps...

[image: revised 51 tap Hilbert]